# Root directory of laravel project in Cloud9

Tags: laravel-5.1, cloud9-ide

now it's showing home page softenum-softenum.c9users.io/public/

it's my site but i could not make root or homepage in softenum-softenum.c9users.io.

Every time I was trying to change DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace/ to DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace/public

But I was not saved by F2 pressing.

Please help me.

Comment: Not entirely sure what your issue is but you might have a look at https://community.c9.io/t/cloud9-adds-port-80-to-laravel-route/475/7 to see if that applies.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same error.
The steps are:

> // Change this line DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace
>
> // To following DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/workspace/public
>
> Press F2
>
> Then 'Y'
>
> Then ENTER

You were missing the ENTER to save it.